# Setting up rtk query with react native

Tags: react-native, rtk-query

I am incorporating Redux Toolkit Query (RTKQ) for state and API management. All I'm trying to do is register a user `onClick` via the register user component:

```
const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = React.useState("");
  const [registerUser] = useRegisterUserMutation();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    registerUser({ name: name, email: email, password: password })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("hi");
      }).
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../assets/Login.jpg")}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={styles.image}
      >
        <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
          <View style={styles.login}>
            <TextInput
              label="Name"
              value={name}
              mode="flat"
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
              label="Email"
              value={email}
              mode="flat"
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
              label="Password"
              value={password}
              // mode="flat"
              style={styles.textInput}
              activeOutlineColor="black"
              onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
              label="Confirm password"
              value={confirmPassword}
              // mode="flat"
              style={styles.textInput}
              activeOutlineColor="black"
              onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={handleSubmit}
              mode="contained"
              dark
              buttonColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)"
              textColor="black"
              // loading
              // style={styles.button}
            >
              Register
            </Button>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RegisterScreen;
```

My api is setup like so:

```js
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000/" }),
  reducerPath: "main",
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    registerUser: build.mutation<User, User>({
      query: ({ ...user }) => ({
        url: "user/register/",
        method: "POST",
        body: user,
      }),
    })
});

export const {
  useRegisterUserMutation
} = api;
```

And my index.js:

```js
dotenv.config();

const PORT = 8000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/user", userRoutes);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log("CONNECTED TO MONGODB");
      console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error connecting to MongoDB: ${err}`);
  });
```

What I don't understand is the function I defined: `handleSubmit` is being called on click and the function is run because I'm seeing 'hi' in my console log but absolutely nothing else is being run.

No user is being added, I'm not getting any errors or any of the console logs from my routes which means the route isn't being hit but then why isn't my catch printing anything?

I'm not sure how RTKQ and `react-native` work together, maybe my store setup was wrong, does anyone know?

Here's my user register route:

```js
import express from "express";
import User from "../models/User.js";
import { hash } from "bcrypt";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const router = express.Router();

const generateToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "30d" });
};

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("User does not exist!");
  }

  if (user && bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
    const token = generateToken(user.id);
    return res.status(200).json({
      _id: user.id,
      token: token,
    });
  }
});

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  console.log(name, email, password);

  if (!name || !email || !password) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("All fields must be filled.");
  }

  console.log(name, email, password);

  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userExists) {
    throw new Error("User already exists!");
  }

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      _id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User not created.");
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: In `handleSubmit` there is ***only*** the `registerUser` call and Promise chain. What else are you expecting to run? *Where* are you expecting a user to be added? The backend? Is the `"/user/register"` endpoint reached? Are you able to inspect the network requests to ensure the outgoing request is correct? Do you get a response, and if so, is it what you expect? This post could benefit from some debugging details.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info and thank you for the edits as usual. When handleSubmit is run, I'm expecting my db to have a user added with the corresponding info. As of right now, I'm getting the following error on my frontend: {"error": "TypeError: Network request failed", "status": "FETCH_ERROR"} and none of my console logs for my register route are being shown which I'm assuming means the route isn't being hit.

Comment: Try Postman to verify your endpoint is accessible and returns responses you expect.

Comment: Ok tried with Postman, all three values (name, email and password) were logged as undefined in the register route

Comment: What about in the request? Are they undefined in the request body? I guess you will just need to trace through the code to find where the values get dropped. From `handleSubmit` to `registerUser`'s `query` function, to the network request, to the backend `"/user/register"` endpoint.

Comment: The entire body is empty when it reaches the endpoint.

Comment: Can you console log `{ name, email, password }` in the submit handler and console log `user` in the `query` function of `registerUser`. Report back the logged values.

Comment: I didn't know you could console log in the query fn, how is that done? Also, the console log in the submit handler is exactly the input I give

Comment: The query function is just a function that returns a query request object. Example: `query: (user) => { console.log({ user }); return { url: "user/register/", method: "POST", body: user, }; }`.

Comment: Oh wow that's super useful, I didn't think I could do that. Both the console log inside the query and inside the handler print the corresponding input. The console logs in the routes print undefined

Comment: Ok, check the out-going network request (browser dev tools, network tab) to ensure the app is making the request properly. If it's correct there then you'll need to go digging in your backend to see where it's getting dropped there.